# How to fit every screen

Tags: android, screen, processing

So I am making a game in `processing`, but I'm not aware as to how to make my game fit every `android` phone's screen, I've looked online, but I can't seem to find anything about it in `Processing`.

I'm fully aware of `displayWidth`/`displayHeight`, but I'm not too sure on how to make my `buttons` to be all pressable, and never change their positions, I would've thought that it would be done by putting all the co-ordinates using something like `displayHeight`/2 etc. etc. But I've tested the game out on my phone(Samsung Galaxy S3), but the text is not aligned properly

If anyone could please help me, I'd be super grateful!

Comment: google "responsive layout"

Comment: @drewmoore I've googled it, yet it mainly talks about xml, but I'm not sure how to apply that to processing?

Answer (score 0):

android devices have different screen size, so instead of using px you can use percentage(%) value for the screen i believe it is sp(a different unit than px) by using this the properties you set for an identity or element becomes constant for all devices

Comment: Thanks alot for even commenting! Could you please use it in an example?

Comment: this should help you http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: how would I use include XMl in processing?